# How to deal with many arguments in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I need to deal with many arguments/options. I think up to 30-40+.

I am using `argparse` (Python 3.5) to let people set the arguments/options from the command line and in the `if __name__ == "__main__":`, I pass all the arguments: `MyClass(arg1, arg2, arg3,...)`.

Is there a better way, more elegant way to do it?

Comment: If you have a lot of command line options, consider using [docopt](http://docopt.org/)

Comment: If your function/class takes keyword args, then `args` from `parse_args` may be passed as `MyClass(**vars(args)`.

Comment: `ipython` builds its `argparse` from values in `config` files.  That way users can specify values in default config, custom config, and commandline. But `ipython` has had a long development time.  `argparse` also has a simple mechanism for reading strings from a file - see its docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than passing lots of arguments to your class, just pass the entire result of `parse_args()` from `argparse`.  Then it's just a single value which contains everything you need.

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll try that. But I'm open for more suggestions :)